# How to find an appropriate object in array by one of its properties

Tags: javascript, json

Say, I have that simple array of objects.

```
var x = [
            {
                id:      1001
                name:    "Jim",
                surname: "Beam"
            },
            {
                id:      1002
                name:    "Jack",
                surname: "Black"
            }
        ]
```

Each object has `id`, `name` and `surname` properties.

How to find an object in array `x` which `id` property is equal to `1002`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to define a find function which takes a predicate

```
function find(arr, predicate) { 
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(arr[i]) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then you can just use this method on the array

```
var found = find(x, function (item) { item.id === 1002 });
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, `find` is part of `Array.prototype` now.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop will suffice:

```
for(var i=0, len=x.length; i < len; i++){
    if( x[i].id === 1002){
        //do something with x[i]
    }
}
```

Even though you are dealing with json remember that it's all just a hierarchy of arrays, objects and primitives.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty obvious solution. :) I've just wondered if there are some lib functions for that task.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits nothing built in, but if you are using something like jQuery or underscore.js you will find niceties that are built in.  I probably would have answered similar to JaredPar if you had asked for the functional way.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits - There is now [something built in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847612/157247).

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2015, JavaScript arrays have [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) methods, both of which are easily polyfilled (see those MDN links for polyfills).

In your case, you'd use `find`:

```
var found = x.find(function(entry) { return entry.id == 1002; });
```

or also using other (non-polyfillable) ES2015 features:

```
const found = x.find(entry => entry.id == 1002);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
            {
                id:      1001
                name:    "Jim",
                surname: "Beam"
            },
            {
                id:      1002
                name:    "Jack",
                surname: "Black"
            }
        ]
const result = data.filter(({id}) => id === 1002);
```

**Filter method** will return **all matching values** as array
If you use **find method** that will return **first matching value**